# Can I pass some parameters with fb.api call in open graph

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Please see these below code which I am using for Facebook Open Graph:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXX" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="collection" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.jpeg"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function postCook() {

        var parameters = new Array();
        parameters["og:title"] = "some_text";

        FB.api(
            'me/<namespace>:<wwwww>',
            'post', {
            collection: 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/'
        },

        function(response) {

            //alert(response.responseText);
            console.log(response);

            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Other22 was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here I want to pass `og:title` and some other also as parameter instead of using in the meta tag. Is there any way to pass some more parameters in FB.api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I could be wrong about this (as Facebook shifts their API around mercilessly), they don't allow you to pass in any custom tag information, possibly as it could be used to misrepresent information.

Instead, once the publish action hits Facebook, Facebook will immediatelly scrape the url passed in, and grab all the meta data it can find, prioritising any open graph tags first before falling back to other traditional methods of meta information retrieval (title tags, scraping the body text, etc).

One possible "workaround" would be to pass an "echo" url to Facebook instead of the target url itself. This relies on you using a server-side solution, however, as I don't believe you can do this with the JS SDK.

i.e. Instead of passing http://www.foobar.com to facebook, pass http://www.barbaz.com/echo.php?title=your%20custom%2otitle&description=etcetc&url=myurl

Tailor the url parameters as necessary, and they will be readable in `echo.php` through `$_GET`. echo.php would then contain the open graph tags to be read by Facebook, and then redirect the user via javascript to the proper URL. Facebook's scraper won't follow the javascript redirect.

echo.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:title" value="<?=$_GET['title']?>">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.location.href = '<?=$_GET['url']?>';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could check for facebook's user-agent string at the top of echo.php and redirect any non-hits to the proper url using `header();`, and only render the bounce page for the facebook bot.

Answer (score 0):

> Here I want to pass og:title and some other also as parameter instead of using in the meta tag.

This is not how Open Graph objects work.

The URL identifies the object, and any data has to be in the HTML code that this URL delivers.